# When I am trying to import XML from a URL this is not working correctly

Tags: c#, xml

Stuggling to get **XML** to import, keep getting

> 403 Error

As a basic, am I code blind and pulling it in wrong?

When I go to http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/?query=artist:coldplay this works.

However I've tried the below code and get a

> 403 error

I've tried a few other things, but the below code is based on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/querying-an-xdocument-vs-querying-an-xelement

```
var url = "http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/?query=artist:coldplay%20AND%20type:group%20AND%20country:GB";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(url);

IEnumerable <XElement> childList =
    from el in doc.Elements()
    select el;

foreach (XElement e in childList)
    Console.WriteLine(e);
```

Additional, I have also tried:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/?query=artist:coldplay");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: The code works fine with https://www.w3schools.com/xml/note.xml but the url you are using is rejecting your query.

Comment: Um, I might message them directly. Their own system code gave me a 403 too. Over thought that, good shout of another URL. Thanks

Comment: Did you try to download the xml with HttpClient instead, and then use LoadXml(string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems in your case the server [was expecting you to set a `UserAgent` header](https://musicbrainz.org/doc/XML_Web_Service/Rate_Limiting#Provide_meaningful_User-Agent_strings) before you can fetch the xml:

```cs
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://musicbrainz.org/ws/2/artist/?query=artist:coldplay");    
request.UserAgent = "My Super Script";
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();  


XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(response.GetResponseStream());

IEnumerable<XElement> childList =
    from el in doc.Elements()
    select el;

foreach (XElement e in childList)
    Console.WriteLine(e);
```

Read more about their API here: https://musicbrainz.org/doc/Development/XML_Web_Service/Version_2